# Require JS optimization

Tags: node.js, requirejs, amd, r.js

I have around 50 JS files and I have to optimize it using r.js and node...
I dont want to specify all the JS files, instead specify the top level folder and somehow let r.js to get all the required js files....

Is there a way to achieve this? Currently I am specifying all the 50 js files in a common js files and referring it in my build.js...I have more files in the coming weeks, and so maintaining a common js file will be a pain.

Please suggest some steps.

here is my build file

```
({   
    baseUrl: ".",
    mainConfigFile: "../App/main.js",
    //modules: [
    //   //{ name: "../App/Crosspoint/Address/AddressList" }
    //   { name: "../App/Crosspoint/Office/OfficeDetails" }
    //],
    //paths: {
    //    app: '../App',
    //    jquery: 'jquery'
    //},
    name: "../App/Crosspoint/Office/OfficeDetails",
    deps: ["../App"],
    out: "main-built123.js",
    rawText: {
        'some/id': 'define(["another/id"], function () {});'
    },
   // dir: "app",    
})
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet similar to what you have in the "Common JS" file with the reference to the 50 different files?

Comment: the common file which I had referred is the config file where we maintain all the script references..say there is a folder A which had B.js, then in the file we will have require(B). (again relative path). I am just thinking to say it in folder level and let r.js scan through the folder to get all the associated script files.

Answer (score 1):

Optimizer should include all the dependencies required by main config file. Also if you have nested dependencies then specify:

```
findNestedDependencies: true
```